# How can I have voice in QtAv with PortAudio

Tags: portaudio

I have compiled QtAv and PortAudio src code, but I run QtAv's examples (such as vo-qt), It only has video, I check the src code, to here AVPlayer.cpp:

HAVE_PORTAUDIO

## include "QtAV/AOPortAudio.h"

and here
/*
HAVE_PORTAUDIO
_audio = new QtAV::AOPortAudio();

*/
so I think PortAudio hasn't included , I don't know where defined the HAVE_PORTAUDIO and how I can include the portaudio?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if your compiler can find portaudio's header and library, then it will be enabled when running qmake.

https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/wiki/Build-QtAV